# second monitor blank after login on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, vga

Primary monitor is DVI (apparently, it is detected by Kubuntu as HDMI)
I added a second monitor, VGA.

At sign-in screen, both monitors show the same display
After login, the second monitor is blank.

In `Displays -- System Settings` the second monitor is greyed out and unconfigurable.

```
System:
  Host: Kubuntu Kernel: 5.3.0-29-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.16.5 Distro: Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine) 
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: B150M-K D3 v: Rev X.0x 
  serial: <filter> UEFI: American Megatrends v: 2604 date: 02/21/2018 
CPU:
  Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-6500 bits: 64 type: MCP 
  L2 cache: 6144 KiB 
  Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 800/3600 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 800 2: 800 
  3: 800 4: 800 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 530 driver: i915 v: kernel 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.5 driver: modesetting 
  unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2) 
  v: 4.5 Mesa 19.2.8 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 100 Series/C230 Series Family HD Audio 
  driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Device-2: JMTek LLC. USB PnP Audio Device type: USB 
  driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.3.0-29-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet 
  driver: r8169 
  IF: enp2s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.14 TiB used: 560.51 GiB (48.1%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Crucial model: CT250BX100SSD1 size: 232.89 GiB 
  ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Western Digital model: WD10EZEX-00BN5A0 
  size: 931.51 GiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 42.81 GiB used: 14.10 GiB (32.9%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda5 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 29.8 C mobo: 27.8 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 0 
Info:
  Processes: 206 Uptime: 25m Memory: 7.66 GiB used: 5.97 GiB (77.9%) 
  Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.36
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It might help to load arandr (the "Screen Layout Editor") and reorient your monitors using the gui. Let arandr generate an xrandr line for you (Layout --> Save As).  arandr is apt-get if you don't already have it.

If execution of the xrandr line displays the output of both monitors, the line can be appended to ~/.profile.  Alternately, one can use the xrandr information in xorg.conf.

Comment: "arandr" does not display the problematic monitor

Comment: Okay, jumped ahead of myself.  `xrandr` alone, without switches, displays the refresh rates of a monitor at different resolutions.  If the monitor is working, you should see the resolution and geometry of the monitor.  If the monitor is _not_ working, `VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)` or similar.  A driver could also be the problem.  I am not familiar with integrated video :-(